# Change background Color for group textfield

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem:**  I have a form that has radio buttons and textfields. What I am trying to do is have a red border appear on the textbox when it is empty. Which I am able to do. However, I would like for the red border to go away when a character is entered in the text field.

I currently have the following:

```
   function SubmitMe() {

     if (document.SubmitIdea.Name.value=="") {
      alert("Please enter your Name.")
      document.SubmitIdea.Name.focus()
      return false
    }

     if (document.SubmitIdea.Department.value=="") {
      alert("Please enter your Department.")
      document.SubmitIdea.Department.focus()
      return false
    }


     if (document.SubmitIdea.Supervisor.value=="") {
      alert("Please enter your Supervisor's Name")
      document.SubmitIdea.Supervisor.focus()
      return false
    }


     if (document.SubmitIdea.NomEmail.value=="") {
      alert("Who enter your email address.")
      document.SubmitIdea.NomEmail.focus()
      return false
    }

    if (document.SubmitIdea.Phone.value=="") {
      alert("Who enter your Phone Number")
      document.SubmitIdea.Phone.focus()
      return false
    }

    myOption = -1;
    var anonymousContainer = document.getElementById('anonymousContainer');
    var anonymousTextField = document.getElementById('anonymousTextField');
    var anonymousInputs = document.getElementsByName('Anonymous');
            for (i=0; i<SubmitIdea.Anonymous.length; i++) {
                if (SubmitIdea.Anonymous[i].checked) {
                    myOption = i;
                }
            }
                if (myOption == -1) {
                    alert("Do you wish to remain anonymous?");
                    anonymousContainer.className += 'borderedContainer';
                    return false;
                }

      if(document.getElementById("textarea1").value=="" && document.getElementById("textarea2").value=="" && document.getElementById("textarea3").value==""){
        alert("Please provide a brief summary of your idea");
      if(document.getElementById("textarea1").value=="") {
        if(document.getElementById("textarea1").value==""){
            anonymousTextField.className += 'borderedContainer';
            return false;
        }
        else
            anonymousTextField.className += 'borderedContainer1';
            return false;
      }
      return false;
      }

     document.SubmitIdea.SubmitIdeaBtn.disabled = true
     document.SubmitIdea.action = "Employee_Ideasp.cfm" 
     document.SubmitIdea.submit()
    }
    function Check(){
                if(document.getElementById('NO').checked) {
                  anonymousContainer.className += 'borderedContainer1';
                }else if(document.getElementById('YES').checked) {
                  anonymousContainer.className += 'borderedContainer1';
                }
    }
<div id="anonymousTextField">
    <textarea name="reason" id="textarea1" cols="6" maxlength="500" class="ideas"
    style="background-color: transparent; color:##000000; font-size:14px;" 
    onFocus="clearTxt(this)" onkeydown="limitTxtArea(this); cntTxt(this, 500, 'cnt');" onkeyup="limitTxtArea(this); cntTxt(this, 500, 'cnt');"></textarea></div>
```

It does not appear to work when I enter text in the text field.

Thank You

Comment: Well, for starters you are making function calls to functions that don't seem to exist

Comment: @JordanS Calling functions to funcitons that dont exist? They do exist

Comment: Not in the code you provided.

Comment: Can you post your code? It's extremely hard to help if we can't see the code...

Comment: Erm... you are making calls from your textarea `limitTxtArea(this); cntTxt(this, 500, 'cnt');` to functions that you still have not posted.

Comment: okay.... I will see what i can do

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using below jquery:

(you need to include jquery to your page if not included).

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = (this.value);

    // if the value is not empty add green border
    if (value != "") {
        $(this).css("border", "5px solid green");
    }
    // if value is empty add red border
    else if (value == "") {
        $(this).css("border", "5px solid red");
    }

}).trigger("change");
```

will apply to all input types

**FIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/x6oar6j1/